# AngularJS - How to check that a specific key has a specific value in an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

In Angular, I have an array like this:

```
$scope.colors =["blue","red","pink","yellow"];
```

And another object

```
$scope.cars=[{"brand":"Ford","color":"blue"},{"brand":"Ferrari","color":"red"},{"brand":"Rolls","color":"blue"}];
```

I would like to do filter, so that

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="n in colors | filter:colorFilter">
    </li>
</ul>
```

The ng-repeat would just display the elements in the `$scope.colors` that exist as values in the `$scope.cars`

So, in other words, it would just display **blue** and **red**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your second array is invalid

Comment: True that. Fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given *colors* and *cars* arrays, you can filter *colors* by:

```js
var colors =["blue","red","pink","yellow"];
var cars=[ {"brand":"Ford","color":"blue"},{"brand":"Ferrari","color":"red"},{"brand":"Rolls","color":"blue"}];

var filteredColors = colors.filter(color => cars.some(car => car.color === color));

console.log(filteredColors);
```

If you cannot use ES6, it should be:

```js
var colors =["blue","red","pink","yellow"];
var cars=[ {"brand":"Ford","color":"blue"},{"brand":"Ferrari","color":"red"},{"brand":"Rolls","color":"blue"}];

var filteredColors = colors.filter(function(color) { 
    return cars.some(function(car) { 
        return car.color === color;
    });
});

console.log(filteredColors);
```

Comment: Thanks, would it be possible to do it without ES6 expressions? (for SEO reasons-as for now googlebot doesn't accept ES6) If not I will mark it as valid

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` method which accepts as parameter a callback function in order to obtain all the colours from each car item from `$scope.cars`, and then use `Set` constructor in order to find out `unique` colours. Then you have to use a `filter` function.

Then you have to use a `filter` function.

```js
let colors =["blue","red","pink","yellow"];
let cars = [{"brand":"Ford","color":"blue"},{"brand":"Ferrari","color":"red"},{"brand":"Rolls","color":"blue"}];
let uniqueColours= [...new Set(cars.map(c => c.color))];
const filteredColors = colors.filter(a=>uniqueColours.includes(a));
console.log(filteredColors);
```

You can do this in a single line:

```js
const colors =["blue","red","pink","yellow"],cars = [{"brand":"Ford","color":"blue"},{"brand":"Ferrari","color":"red"},{"brand":"Rolls","color":"blue"}],
filteredColors = colors.filter(a => cars.map(a => a.color).includes(a));
console.log(filteredColors);
```

Without arrow functions.

```js
const colors =["blue","red","pink","yellow"],cars = [{"brand":"Ford","color":"blue"},{"brand":"Ferrari","color":"red"},{"brand":"Rolls","color":"blue"}],
filteredColors = colors.filter(function(a){ 
    return cars.map(function(c){
       return c.color;
    }).includes(a)});
console.log(filteredColors);
```

Comment: Thanks, I think both answers are valid, I will mark @Faly as correct as he was the first to answer, but for angular it would be optimal if the solution would not have ES6 expressions (as for today googlebot breaks with ES6)

Comment: @Joe82, i added a solution without ES6