# Angular JS - Apply Javascript filtering logic to Angular Filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This question comes from  [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48113440/angularjs-how-to-check-that-a-specific-key-has-a-specific-value-in-an-array/48113512)

In Javascript, I have this code in order to make a filtering, so that I can show the elements from the array `colors` just when they also appear as a value in `cars`

```
var colors = ["blue","red","pink","yellow"];

var cars = [{"brand":"Ford","color":"blue"}
           ,{"brand":"Ferrari","color":"red"}
           ,{"brand":"Rolls","color":"blue"}];

var filteredColors = colors.filter(function(color) { 
    return cars.some(function(car) { 
        return car.color === color;
    }); 
});

console.log(filteredColors);
```

I have tried to apply this in Angular JS, doing this:

```
$scope.colors =["blue","red","pink","yellow"];

$scope.cars=[ {"brand":"Ford","color":"blue"}
           ,{"brand":"Ferrari","color":"red"}
           ,{"brand":"Rolls","color":"blue"}];

$scope.filteredColors = function() {
    var colorsvar = $scope.colors;
    var carsvar = $scope.cars;
    return colorsvar.filter(function(color) { 
        return carsvar.some(function(car) { 
            return car.color === color;
        });
    });

};
```

And then in the view:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="n in colors | filter: filteredColors"> {{n}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

The result should be

**blue**

**red**

But it doesn't happen to filter properly. See working plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/d8arqXSgTSbbxLDbBOsX) Any help will be welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom filter as below, check the DEMO

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
$scope.colors =["blue","red","pink","yellow"];

$scope.cars=[ {"brand":"Ford","color":"blue"}
           ,{"brand":"Ferrari","color":"red"}
           ,{"brand":"Rolls","color":"blue"}];

 
})
app.filter('myFilter', function() {
    // the filter takes an additional input filterIDs
    return function( filterColors, inputArray) {
        var filtered = [];
       angular.forEach(inputArray,function(key,value){
             if(filterColors.includes(key.color) && !filtered.includes(key.color)) {
                filtered.push(key.color);
             }
       })
       return filtered;
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="n in colors | myFilter: cars  track by $index"> {{n}}
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in the question, the ng-repeat should be "n in colors", and it should yield as the result "blue" and "red" (no "blue", "red", "blue")

Comment: Good Explination

Answer (score 1):

No need to call a filter. just call the function inside the `ng-repeat`

```
 <li ng-repeat="n in filteredColors()"> {{n}}
 </li>
```

Demo

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
$scope.colors =["blue","red","pink","yellow"];

$scope.cars=[ {"brand":"Ford","color":"blue"}
           ,{"brand":"Ferrari","color":"red"}
           ,{"brand":"Rolls","color":"blue"}];

$scope.filteredColors = function() {
    var colorsvar = $scope.colors;
    var carsvar = $scope.cars;
    return colorsvar.filter(function(color) { 
        return carsvar.some(function(car) { 
            return car.color === color;
        });
    });

};
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="n in filteredColors()"> {{n}}
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there it any way to apply it as a filter?  (I think I need that approach for my app) If not I will mark it as correct anyway. Thanks!

Comment: check this https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-custom-angularjs-filters