# Angular JS - Filter when value in specific key in one array also appears as value in specific key in another array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This questions comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48117076/angular-js-apply-javascript-filtering-logic-to-angular-filter/48118032#48118032)

I want to make a filtering, so that I can show the values of colors.name just when they also appear as a value in cars.color

```
$scope.colors = [{"name":"blue","count":2},
                 {"name":"red","count":12},
                 {"name":"pink","count":5},
                 {"name":"yellow","count":2}];

$scope.cars=[ {"brand":"Ford","color":"blue", "seat":"pink"}
       ,{"brand":"Ferrari","color":"red", "seat":"pink"}
       ,{"brand":"Rolls","color":"blue","seat":"pink"}];
```

And then in the view:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="n in colors | filter: filteredColors"> {{n}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

The result should be

**blue**

**red**

I need the answer not to have ES6, and I need the filter to be in the controller. See plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/d8arqXSgTSbbxLDbBOsX?p=preview). Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are differences in the plnkr and your example. Are they intentional, if they are, which one is the source of truth?

Comment: Yep, sorry, updated the plunkr now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

controller:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.colors = [{"name":"blue","count":2},
                 {"name":"red","count":12},
                 {"name":"pink","count":5},
                 {"name":"yellow","count":2}];

  $scope.cars=[ {"brand":"Ford","color":"blue", "seat":"pink"}
       ,{"brand":"Ferrari","color":"red", "seat":"pink"}
       ,{"brand":"Rolls","color":"blue","seat":"pink"}];

  $scope.filteredColors = function(color) {
    var carsvar = $scope.cars;
    for(var x = 0; x < carsvar.length; x++) {
      if (color.name === carsvar[x].color) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false; 
  };

});
```

view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.6/angular.js" data-semver="1.6.6"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="color in colors | filter: filteredColors"> {{color.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: btw $scope.colors, cars in your plunker don't match your question, but I just copied them over to plunker and works fine :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but for my user case, I need a filter that could be applied to the ng-repeat (not an "already filtered" scope).

Comment: @Joe82, ah, finally understood you.  I've updated my answer which now produces  * blue * red using a filter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom filter:

```
 app.filter('colorFilter', function(){
    return function(val){
        var colorsvar = [{"name":"blue","count":2},
             {"name":"red","count":12},
             {"name":"pink","count":5},
             {"name":"yellow","count":2}];
        var filtered = []
        angular.forEach(val, function(key, value){
                angular.forEach(colorsvar, function(key2, value2){
                     if(key.color === key2.name)
                         filtered.push(key)
                })
        })
        return filtered;
    }
})
```

And then on your html:

```
<li ng-repeat="n in cars | colorFilter"> {{n.color}}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, but I couldn't make it work in my plunkr. I would as well need the filter inside the controller.

Answer (score 0):

As per your first question, there have some answers without using ES6. [AngularJS - How to check that a specific key has a specific value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48113440/angularjs-how-to-check-that-a-specific-key-has-a-specific-value-in-an-array/48113512)

So I thought you don't need to use any inbuilt function to  do your logic.

Try to use with manual `loop` instead of using `map` or `include` bla bla bla..  Do Just like a normal `JavaScript` way in `angularjs`. Get this answer as a key. Take this answer as a key and do it with `angular.filter()`.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
$scope.colors  = [{"name":"blue","count":2},
             {"name":"red","count":12},
             {"name":"pink","count":5},
             {"name":"yellow","count":2}];



$scope.cars=[ {"brand":"Ford","color":"blue"}
           ,{"brand":"Ferrari","color":"red"}
           ,{"brand":"Rolls","color":"blue"}];

$scope.filteredColors = function () {
var colorsvar = $scope.colors;
var carsvar = $scope.cars;
$scope.newValue = [];
for (var i = 0; i < colorsvar.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < carsvar.length; j++) {
        if (colorsvar[i].name == carsvar[j].color) {
            if ($scope.newValue.indexOf(colorsvar[i].name) ==-1) {
                $scope.newValue.push(colorsvar[i].name);
            }
        }
    }
}
   return $scope.newValue;
  };
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="n in filteredColors()"> {{n}}
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments!

Comment: I didn't comment here.